# JEditorPane in html mode cuts last empty space when using setText

Tags: java, html, swing

I have set my JEditorPane to use the text/html kit. If I try to setText("hey ") for example (note the space after 'hey'), the editor pane displays just "hey", there is no space after. Does somebody know how I can solve this?

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why are you worried about this?

If you want simple unformatted text to be displayed, then use a `JTextArea` or `JTextPane`.

A `JEditorPane` is used to "format" text so it will parse the data and may remove unwanted characters.

If you want to force a space when using HTML then you can use:

```
editor.setText("hello&nbsp");
```

Comment: Thank you! I was so worried because I was implementing a syntax highlighter using HTML to color my code and every time I entered a space in the JEditorPane, formatted it to html and then set it back I would lose the space, so I could basically not have any words.

Comment: @Calin I see you got your question solved and accepted this answer. However for further questions you might have, please consider adding your code here and not inside an image, it's better for us (and the site) in case your image gets deleted and also a code we can copy-paste and sometimes images are just too low quality that it becomes unreadable :)

Comment: @Calin, `I was implementing a syntax highlighter` - I would use a JTextPane. It is much easier to work with attributes than HTML. With attributes you don't change the text at all. You just add an attribute when you want to color some text. Check out [Text Component Features](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/generaltext.html) for some basics of using attributes.